# Pie Chart Using Raw Data

Tags: matlab

I have 4 types of objects with labels 1,2,3 and 4.

Now, I have `N` objects as a vector of `Nx1` where each element corresponds to the class of the object.

So, if I have `5` objects, I might have a vector that looks like

```
D = [1,1,3,4,2]
```

What I want to do is the get a pie chart for the data `D`. 
A hotch-potch way of doing it is:

```
count_data = zeros(4,1);
for it=1:4
count_data(it) = sum(D==it);
end
pie(count_data)
```

Is there a clean way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`histc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histc.html) to count occurences of integers (among other uses). Instead of your for-loop put `count_data = histc(D, 1:4)`.